# Trouble using SOQL to filter results by a range of Dates - What is the correct syntax?

Tags: soql, api

Using the Salesforce API, I am trying to search for Cases which have a CreatedDate between two specific dates, but I am getting errors when sending my query.

For example:

```
SELECT Id FROM Case  
WHERE  CreatedDate >= 2013-12-21  AND  CreatedDate <= 2013-12-23
```

The error I get is:

```
value of filter criterion for field 'CreatedDate' 
must be of type dateTime and should not be enclosed in quotes
```

I read the ["Date Formats and Date Literals"](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) article and do not see where the issue is in my query.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`CreatedDate` is of DateTime type so your query must use the format from the very top of the article you've linked to: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ` (optionally with timezones)

```
SELECT Id 
FROM Case  
WHERE CreatedDate >= 2013-12-21T00:00:00Z
AND CreatedDate <= 2013-12-23T23:59:59Z
```

Another example:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE CreatedDate > 2005-10-08T01:02:03Z
```

Comment: At the very top of the article: "Date only  YYYY-MM-DD  1999-01-01" @eyescream

Comment: You can get used to it. I prefer to think that Date/Time-related queries are weird in any single DB engine, Oracle forces you to write `TO_DATE` like there's no tomorrow and don't get me started on MSSQL's magic format "112". The `CreatedDate` name is bit misleading... If you prefer to query the simple way - make a formula field of type Date maybe and filter on it instead? `DATE(YEAR(CreatedDate), MONTH(CreatedDate), DAY(CreatedDate))` should be enough.

Comment: I'm used to SQL, where I can throw a Date without extraneous time information against DateTime fields and have it not have a seizure. Also, I can't take your suggestion because I can't actually modify anything about my company's Salesforce environment - I can only use the API to query things for reporting purposes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also note there is a difference between filtering `Date` and `DateTime`. You must filter `Date` type using `2014-12-31` and `DateTime` type using `2014-12-31T00:00:00Z`

Answer (score 5):

### Salesforce filtering by date examples:

All these SOQL queries are working for me on Salesforce API version 29

**Greater than a certain time:**

```
SELECT count(Id) 
FROM Lead
WHERE createdDate > 2015-02-01T00:00:00Z
```

**Greater than yesterday:**

```
SELECT count(Id)
FROM Lead
WHERE createdDate > YESTERDAY
```

**Greater than 62 days ago:**

```
SELECT id
FROM Lead
WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:62
LIMIT 100
```

**Greater than last week:**

```
SELECT Id
FROM Lead
WHERE createdDate > LAST_WEEK
```

**This year:**

```
SELECT Id
FROM Lead
WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) = 2015
```

**Get the current Year returned:**

```
SELECT CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate)
FROM Opportunity
group by CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate)
```